# Prev nex buttons on a slide show.

Tags: jquery

I have the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

$('.showcase-content .description').jScrollPane();

$(".beericon").click(function() {
        var imgnumber = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace("imglink", ""));
        var move = -($("#img"+imgnumber).width() * (imgnumber - 1));

        $("#img_box").animate({
            left: move
        }, 500);

        $("#beerview_icons").find("div").removeAttr("style");
        $("#imglink"+imgnumber).css("background-position", "0px -74px");

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and it applies to:

```
<div id="img_container">
      <div id="img_box"> <img id="img1" src="../images/lightbox_brew_photos/cutthroat.png"/> <img id="img2" src="../images/beer_in_glasses/Cutthroat.png"/> 
<img id="img3" src="../images/lightbox_brew_photos/Cutthroat-6-Pack.png" style="margin-top:290px;"/> 
<img id="img4" src="../images/lightbox_brew_photos/Cutthroat-12-Pack.png" style="margin-top:335px;"/>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="beerview_icons">
      <div class="beericon" id="imglink1" style="background-position:0px -74px;"></div>
      <div class="beericon" id="imglink2"></div>
      <div class="beericon" id="imglink3"></div>
      <div class="beericon" id="imglink4"></div>
      <br class="clearfloat" />
    </div>
```

Is there a way to ammend the js so that it's a basic previous next nav? I have to add more images and it's a smaller space for thumbs. Figured it'd be easier to try and write some thing than redo it with a different slide show.